# Date time format in PowerShell returning incorrect date in powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to change text 11.30 to time format 11:30 using [datetime] in powershell

```
$Stime = "11.30"
$time = "{00:hh:mm}" -f [datetime]$Stime
Write-Host $time
```

This code returns value 12:00

I tried this too -

```
$fromtime = "11.30"
[datetime]$fromtime12hrFormat = ([datetime]$fromtime)
$fromtime12hrFormat.ToString("hh:mm:ss")
```

This code returns value 12:00

Comment: you need to deal with the ambiguous date time format. something like this >>> `[datetime]::ParseExact($STime, 'HH.mm', $Null)` <<< should do the job. [*grin*] that gives me `11:30 am` with the date set to today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"11.30"` cast to `[datetime]` with `en-US` locale will be interpreted as "November 30" at midnight.

Use [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact) instead:

```
'{0:HH:mm}' -f [datetime]::ParseExact($Stime, 'HH.mm', $null)
```